# Local HTML file not loading CSS file in browser

Tags: html, css

I am trying to run an HTML file from my computer in Google Chrome.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Fighting Program</title>
        <link rel=¨stylesheet¨ href="styles.css" type="text/css"></link>
    script src="..\JavaScript\script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
       <p>Test</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is my CSS

```
    body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(red,black); 

        margin: 0;
        height: 100vh;
    
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: red;
    }
```

I know my CSS works because I put it in a `<style>` tag and it looks just fine. By using my browser development tools, I looked and saw that the pathway was correct as it displayed the CSS information.

I've gone over and over Stack Overflow, trying many different answers and none of them seem to work for me.

Comment: You have the wrong quotes around `rel`

Comment: Of course, my code would be foiled over the wrong quotations. Thank you @epascarello!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use and IDE like VSCode instead of a plain old text editor like I assume you are using.

Comment: Your script tag is malformed. You’re missing the opening < on the script tag.

Comment: btw you can skip the 2nd line. the first line !DOCTYPE html is already the opening tag for html. no need to write another opening tag for it into the 2nd line. Then a link tag in the ehader doesnt need a closing tag the right formatting is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

The CSS file should be linked in this way. Also please make sure to check your CSS file path and make sure it is accurate.
For example this my CSS file path.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

Just in case you didn't add your CSS file to any folder it should look something like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Also if you add `style` in your HTML it means it is internal CSS which will load for sure.